# Group (previous) elements of array by number of subsequent negative ones

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to process (in C#) a large data file with some numeric data. Given an array of integers, how can it be split/grouped, so that previous *n* elements are grouped if next *n* (two or more) are negative numbers. For example, in the array below, two or more consecutive negative numbers should be used as a hint to group the same number of previous elements:

```
0 
1
4 
-99
-99
-99
1 
2 
7 
9 
-99
-99
3 
6 
8 
-99
-99
5
```

Output:

```
Group 1:
0 
1
4 
[3 negative numbers were next, so group previous 3]

Group 2:
1 

Group 3:
2 

Group 4:
7 
9 
[2 negative numbers were next, so group previous 2, but keep any prior positive numbers (1, 2) as separate groups]

Group 5:
3 

Group 6:
6 
8 
[2 negative numbers were next, so group previous 2, but keep any prior positive numbers (3) as separate groups]

Group 7:
5
```

What will be the fastest, most efficient way to process such an array of data into a new grouped collection?

Comment: Are you definitely able to load the whole file into an array? That may make it simpler, but it'll be less memory-efficient than an algorithm which only needs to accept an `IEnumerable<int>` for example.

Comment: Yes @JonSkeet, whole file can be loaded in an array (or any other Enumerable, if needed).

Comment: Righto. Trying to write a streaming version anyway, but may then adapt :)

Comment: May be easier to process the array in reverse?

Comment: What should we do if we see just a single negative number? e.g. 1, 2, -99, 3, 4. Should that emit {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}?

Comment: @DavidG Makes sense. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @JonSkeet Single negative numbers can be ignored or treated as a positive number (to be grouped separately). Edit: Yes, your example is valid.

Comment: Okay. It sounds like that doesn't need to be a rule at all then - it behaves "naturally".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably try to stream the whole thing, maintaining a buffer of "current non-negative numbers" and a count of negative numbers. Here's some code which appears to work... I'd expect it to be at least *pretty* efficient. I'd start with that, and if it's not efficient enough for you, look into why.

(If you do want to have the whole array in memory, you don't need to build up the `numbersToEmit` list, as you can just maintain indexes instead. But given that a single list is reused, I'd expect this to be okay.)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] input = { 0, 1, 4, -99, -99, -99, 1, 
                2, 7, 9, -99, -99, 3, 6, 8, -99, -99, 5 };
        foreach (var group in GroupByNegativeCounts(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", group));
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<int[]> GroupByNegativeCounts(IEnumerable<int> input)
    {
        List<int> numbersToEmit = new List<int>();
        int negativeCount = 0;
        foreach (var value in input)
        {
            // We never emit anything when we see a negative number
            if (value < 0)                
            {
                negativeCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                // We emit numbers if we've previously seen negative
                // numbers, and then we see a non-negative one.
                if (negativeCount > 0)
                {
                    int singles = Math.Max(numbersToEmit.Count - negativeCount, 0);
                    foreach (var single in numbersToEmit.Take(singles))
                    {
                        yield return new[] { single };
                    }
                    if (singles != numbersToEmit.Count)
                    {
                        yield return numbersToEmit.Skip(singles).ToArray();
                    }
                    negativeCount = 0;
                    numbersToEmit.Clear();
                }
                numbersToEmit.Add(value);
            }
        }
        // Emit anything we've got left at the end.
        foreach (var single in numbersToEmit)
        {
            yield return new[] { single };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'll give it a try, and see how it goes. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, I tried to make it as simple as possible :)

```
    List<int> input = new List<int>() { 0, 1, 4, -99, -99, -99, 1, 2, 7, 9, -99, -99, 3, 6, 8, -99, -99, 5 };
    List<int> reverse_input = input.Reverse<int>().ToList();    //reverse list for easier reading
    List<List<int>> grouped_input = new List<List<int>>();      //output variable

    List<int> leading_positives;
    int leading_negative_count;

    while (reverse_input.Any())
    {
        //Get the amount of leading negatives and remove them from the reversed list
        leading_negative_count = reverse_input.TakeWhile(num => num < 0).Count();
        reverse_input = reverse_input.Skip(leading_negative_count).ToList();

        //get and store leading positives and remove them from the reversed list
        leading_positives = reverse_input.TakeWhile(num => num >= 0).ToList();
        reverse_input = reverse_input.Skip(leading_positives.Count).ToList();

        //take an amount of positives equal to the amount of previously found negatives and add them as a separate list to the output
        grouped_input.Add(leading_positives.Take(leading_negative_count).Reverse().ToList());

        //for each remaining positive add it as an individual into the output
        leading_positives.Skip(leading_negative_count).ToList().ForEach(num => grouped_input.Add(new List<int>() { num }));               
    }

//output display       
grouped_input.Reverse<List<int>>().ToList().ForEach(lst => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", lst)));
```